# Для чего нужны классы?

Tags: php, ооп, классы

Не понимаю, для чего нужны классы в PHP?

Допустим, есть `function.php`, в нём много много функций, выполняющих разные действия, функции частично содержат общие переменные и в некоторых случаях части их кодов совпадают.

Если все эти функции превратить в методы и засунуть в один класс, что изменится в лучшую сторону или по другому - для чего нужны классы?

Comment: ну хотя бы группировка функций по логическим задачам

Comment: использование ООП не делает ваш код читабельнее и легче в поддержке, это делает программист, ООП лишь, в некоторых случаях, может в этом помочь.

Comment: @AlexWindHope: Я и вправду выразился, возможно, излишне категорично. Тем не менее, гляньте PS в ответе.

Comment: @Zowie, как раз таки наоборот: использование ООП **делает** ваш код читабельнее и **легче** в поддержке

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Пример работы с БД:

```
$con = db_connect($data);
$query = db_query($con, $data);
$fetch = db_fetch($query);
```

Опять же, нужна глобальная переменная `$con`, проверка результата каждый раз и т.п.

Или вот класс:

```
/** 
 * @author
 *
 * @todo
 */
class Db {
    private $con, $query, $fetch;
    /**
     *
     */
    function __construct($data) {
        return $this->con = db_connect($data);
    }
    /**
     *
     */
    function query($data) {
        if($this->con) {
            $this->query = db_query($this->con, $data);

            return $this;
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception('no connection to db');
        }
    }
    /**
     *
     */
    function fetch() {
        if($this->con) {
            return $this->fetch = db_fetch($this->query);
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception('no connection to db');
        }       
    }
    /**
     *
     */
    function __destruct() {
        db_close($this->con);
    }
    /**
     *
     */
    public static function create($data) {
        return new Db($data);
    }
}

$Db = Db::create('host:localhost;login:1234...');

$fetch = $Db->query('SELECT * FROM db')->fetch();
```

Простенько запускаем, делаем запрос и выводим результат. Красиво, удобно.

Comment: @lampa, Вам самому-то не смешно от своего примера?

Было 3 строчки, стало 30 (не считая комментариев). Вы считаете, что в 30-ти разобраться легче?

Comment: @avp кому какое дело, какая магия в классе творится? Я еще не добавил в эти 3 строчки проверку результатов, бинды (например как в PDO) и прочую лобуду. В итоге-то получается 2 строки + удобство на лицо.

Comment: @avp, вам не кажется, что в 3-х строчках сверху не хватает еще описаний собственно ф-ций `db_connect`, `db_query` и `db_fetch`? Представьте, если бы был этот листинг. Было бы меньше 30?

Но если все же сравнивать количество строк, то тогда можно сказать, что в первом случае мы написали 3 строки, а во втором — 2.

Comment: Вы минимум заметили одну вещь, он может сделать $Db = Db::create('host:localhost;login:1234...'); $Db2 = Db::create('host:localhost;login:XX...'); и работать с двумя базами одновременно!

Answer (score 35):

(*Резюме: классы нужны, чтобы абстрагироваться от сложности задания.*)

Вы серьёзно не знаете, для чего нужны классы? Хм. Ну ладно.

Давайте подумаем: что такое программирование? Программирование -- это *производство*. Я имею в виду не учебные задания в стиле «введите строку и посчитайте в ней количество пробелов». Я имею в виду реально *большие* проекты. В них не так уж часто встречаются особо умные куски кода, зато функциональности *много*, она не обязательно логично устроена (особенно часто такое бывает, если вы конструируете интерфейс пользователя), и, что немаловажно, проект поддерживают не гении, вроде всех на этом сайте, а обычные программисты.

Это значит, что большая часть времени жизни кода уйдёт на его *поддержку*, а не начальную разработку.

Гении (и начинающие программисты тоже, как ни странно) не любят доводить что-то до совершенства. Они напишут прототип в виде одной офигенно сложной функции, и voila! — задание выполнено. В функции есть тысяча хитростей и зависимостей, которые гению просто держать в голове. Но завтра гений заболеет, уйдёт в запой или вообще уволится — и внезапно код должны поддерживать самые обыкновенные обыкновенные программисты, из мяса и костей.

А обыкновенному программисту нелегко работать с длинной сложной функцией, при одном взгляде на неё начинает болеть голова. Он не может держать в голове сразу миллионы понятий и зависимостей! И тут внезапно на помощь приходят классы. Классы позволяют *уменьшить сложность*. Когда программист разрабатывает класс, он, конечно, думает обо *всём* классе и держит в голове сразу *весь* класс. Но когда он разрабатывает другие классы, он думает больше не в терминах «я вызову функцию X, и она установит переменную Y», а в терминах классов: «я беру возраст пользователя», «я рисую эту картинку». Теперь голова болит гораздо меньше: вместо того, чтобы думать о всех функциях в проекте одновременно, программист думает только о немногих публичных функциях немногих публичных интерфейсов. Таким образом, в его коде меньше *зависимостей*: он не должен думать (вернее *должен не думать!*) о конкретной реализации возраста пользователя, или там отрисовки картинки, он может про это забыть. Его код становится проще, этот код легче понимать, тестировать и поддерживать.

Кроме того, он больше не должен думать что-то типа «я добавляю пользователя в список модераторов, для этого мне надо обновить вот этот массив, вот ту хэш-таблицу, поставить флаг для обновления базы данных и не забыть ещё увеличить счётчик версий». Он просто говорит: «таблица модераторов, добавь-ка в себя вот этого пользователя!» То есть теперь можно думать не в терминах внутренних структур данных, а в терминах *семантики*: программист пишет прямо то, что он хочет выразить. Несмотря на то, что в языке не было раньше конструкций для выражения его мыслей. Мы видим, что программист на самом деле *расширяет* язык под свою предметную область, и может легко и адекватно выражать своё намерение. Такой код не только легче писать, но и легче поддерживать.

При этом эффективность кода может падать по сравнению кодом, учитывающим особенности реализации других классов, но мы сознательно идём на эту жертву: наша цель — чтобы код стал проще, яснее, чтобы он говорил сам за себя!

Обратите внимание, что этот подход — развитие процедурного подхода: там мы складывали код в процедуры, чтобы абстрагироваться от кода одной процедуры во время разработки другой (и код, который опирается на конкретику реализации, обычно считается *плохим*, потому что он *не уменьшает* количество абстракций, которые нужно держать в голове). Так и при объектном-ориентированном подходе уменьшается, в свою очередь, количество *функций*, которые надо держать в голове.

Кроме того, ООП даёт другие плюшки, в виде наследования и полиморфизма, которые, однако, кажутся мне концептуально менее важными. Хотя и очень приятными в использовании.

Таким образом, для маленького проекта, для которого вы *можете* держать все функции в голове, можно отказаться от использования классов. Но для достаточного большого, серьёзного проекта без помощи классов для уменьшения сложности не обойтись.

---

PS: Для разработчиков на C: в самом деле, можно уменьшать сложность и по-другому, например, не выносить нерелевантный код в заголовочные файлы. Классы в языках, которые их поддерживают, предоставляют *явное* средство управления сложностью, в отличие от *неявного*, осуществляемого в C.

Comment: Браво) дочитал=)

Comment: @Palmervan: спасибо! (делаю реверанс)

Comment: @VladD, в теории (т.е. как должно быть) это все правильно.

    Резюме: классы нужны, чтобы абстрагироваться от сложности задания

Вы уверены, что на практике получается именно так? 

IMHO обычно более подходит следующая цитата Черномырдина:

    ...хотели, как лучше, а получилось как всегда...

или (из Булгакова, дословно не помню)

    разруха не в сортирах, а в головах

ООП, которое уже лет 20 активно навязывается, это попытка сделать методику построения эффективных (в широком смысле) систем *пригодную для применения многими людьми во всех случаях*. 

Не уверен, что такое вообще возможно.

Comment: @avp: прямых рук ничто не заменит, и если программист плох, никакое ООП его не спасёт. Однако избыточная сложность мешает и _хорошим_ программистам, и для них ООП позволяет держать сложность под контролем. К сожалению, _некоторые_ программисты ухитряются с ООП получить такой же spaghetti, как и без него, а то и хуже. Но это уж с любым оружием так: оно полезно только если прилично им владеть.

Comment: @VladD, это безусловно так. 

Единственное **НО**. Часто применение методов ООП, особенно в сочетании со стремлением к универсальности и повторному использованию (желаемое выдается за действительное) решения, приводит не к упрощению, а к усложнению *конкретного* продукта.

Все это, конечно, достаточно абстрактный разговор. Об оптимальности проектных решений можно говорить только применительно к конкретной задаче.

Comment: @avp: я согласен с вами на все 100, применение ООП делает продукт **в целом** сложнее. Но разработка каждого отдельного компонента при правильно и последовательно применённом ООП становится проще. Таким образом, мы платим глобальной выросшей сложностью за локальную простоту.

Comment: Получается так что классами не все программисты пользуются и это нормальное явление?

Comment: Если программист один, он сам себе решает, какими техниками он пользуется. Если программистов много, они должны между собой договориться. В принципе, пользоваться или нет, в каждом проекте решается отдельно. Хотя по тренду последних 20 лет, для достаточно сложных проектов ООП считается обязательным, вы вполне можете этому тренду не следовать. С другой стороны, вы имеете право отказаться от процедурного программирования тоже, если вы -- хозяин кода.

Comment: > Но для достаточного большого, серьёзного проекта без помощи классов для уменьшения сложности не обойтись.

Позвольте не согласиться, от имени C разработчиков.

Comment: @AlexWindHope: добавил PS

Answer (score 14):

ООП - вообще, а не только в PHP - это всего лишь навсего другое представление процедурного программирования.

Компилятор (интерпретатор) при парсинге классов заменяет все на обычные функции.

**Было:**

```
class ClassA {
    public $item;
    public function MethodA() {};
}
```

**Стало:**

```
ClassA = object {
    $item;
}

function MethodA(ClassA $object) {};
```

И все вызовы, соответственно, заменяются: ClassA->methodA() => methodA(ClassA);

Т.е. в интерпретируемых языках обратное преобразование (из класса в функции) постоянно занимает некоторое время (в компилируемых занимает только на этапе компиляции).

Зачем тогда же вводят это ООП, в том числе и в PHP?

1) Уже было сказано - достаточно в одно месте сделать необходимые вычисления (проверки, тригеры и т.д.) - и не надо будет об этом заботиться дальше. Да и менять потом придется в одном месте - в классе, а не искать и исправлять по всем файлам

2) Сопровождать этот код (с использованием ООП) в больших проектах - намного проще, чем искать по всем функциям по всем файлам.

Можно, конечно, разделить функции по смыслу и запихать их в соответствующие файлики, но чем тогда этот подход будет отличаться от ООП? Отличаться будет, конечно, т.к. у ООП еще куча своих плюшек, но в этом плане - аналогия почти полная

3) Именование - в различных классах имена переменных могут пересекаться как угодно. Используя глобальные переменные вы этого не добьетесь.

4) Проектируя какой-нибудь объект вы ожидаете от него определенного поведения. Если использовать обычные функции, то где будет уверенность, что нужную сейчас глобальную переменную вы не поменяете где-нибудь еще в какой-нибудь левой функции без предупреждения?

5) и 6) и 7) и т.д. - все в книгах расписано, всего здесь не напишешь.

Главное - почти все, что реализуется с использованием ООП можно реализовать используя функции. И при небольшом количестве строк кода функции будут заметно выигрывать у ООП, а не правильно используя ООП можно вообще завести проект в дебри.

Ведь вы же в магазин не на самолете летаете? И в отпуск не пешком ходите?

Так и здесь - до тех пор пока что-то замечательно справляется с поставленной задачей, то зачем это что-то менять? Но это именно "*до тех пор пока что-то замечательно справляется с поставленной задачей*".

Comment: Кстати, private и protected внесены в классы только ради удобства.

Скрыв нужные переменные можно не проверять их каждый раз, т.к. изменить их проблематично. Если конечно, вы сами в коде где-то не напутали.

"Проблематично" - значит способ есть) Компилим приложение, смотрим на области памяти, находим наши private и protected и обращаемся к ним напрямую))

Но вообще - если что-то private, значит оно и должно быть private. Если вы расширяете область видимости этой переменной, то скорее всего где-то что-то вы делаете неправильно...

Comment: > ООП - вообще, а не только в PHP - это всего лишь навсего другое представление процедурного программирования.

Глубокое заблуждение. ООП это не про то как структуры и функции собирать в кучу, а про полиморфизм и наследование. Про поведение.

Comment: @Vladimir Gordeev, Про поведение я тоже писал. И покажите мне код основанный на классах, который я не смогу реализовать через процедуры.

Другое представление дает другие возможности. В этом я с вами не спорю.

>>ООП - вообще, а не только в PHP - это всего лишь навсего другое представление процедурного программирования

Это для компилятора так, я писал.

Answer (score 8):

В чём-то с вами я согласен, сам классами пользоваться не спешу, хотите вы этого или нет, но классы - это тоже хорошая нагрузка на сценарий. Вообще классы удобны, когда приходится как-то группировать функции(а в них они методы), например, может быть метод с одинаковым названием в разных классах, но с разным предназначением и кодом. Сам лично начал изучать классы тогда, когда пришлось править чужой код. Пользоваться классами или нет - решать вам,   но а для чего они всё же нужны, вроде как знаю, понимаю, а описать не могу, но в основном для какой-то классификации.

Comment: На мой взгляд ООП в php сделано исключительно ради лулзов, когда используешь классы уменьшается производительность и добавляется куча новых строк кода. Но когда проект большой, то ООП так помогает разделать функции по полочкам, а для маленьких проектов (например просто блог) это не к чему.

Answer (score 5):

Суть не сколько в классах, а конкретно в [ООП](http://php.su/learnphp/phpoo/), и потребности его использования!

> Допустим есть у меня файл function.php

Дело в том что он у всех есть, не зависимо от того используется ли ООП в проекте или нет, радовой функционал не выбросишь, как не крути.

Ну и конечно как высказались выше "группировка функций по логическим задачам". А главное, это очень удобно.

Answer (score 5):

## Если вы пишете простую программу, ООП не нужен.

**I.** Простую программу на пару сотен строчек можно никак не организовывать, и вы не почувствуете необходимости в ООП. Это одна из проблем при обучении ООП: в нём реально возникает необходимость, только если вы работаете со сложной системой, а примеры почему-то всегда используют бестолковые, на пару строчек. Разумеется, это вызывает неприятие.

Для простого смертного прикладного программиста (ака любителя *императивного* кода) обычно самым простым кодом является **процедурное программирование**. Если вам для ваших задач хватает его — пользуйтесь им.

**II.** Во многих ответах выше описывают не *объектно-ориентированное программирование*, а **"недо-объектное" программирование**, когда функции просто раскидываются по классам. В итоге, вместо `$foo = foo_create(); foo_call_baz($foo, 123, $baz)` вы пишете `$foo = new Foo(); $foo->call_baz(123, $baz)`. Разница исключительно на уровне синтаксиса: ставить первый аргумент функции в начале или посередине, использовать для работы с объектами функции с префиксом или писать "присоединять" название функции к переменной.

Подобное "недо-объектное" программирование — это естественный следующий шаг после процедурного программирования. Несмотря на весьма небольшие отличия, работать с объектами несколько *удобнее*: все функции собираются в одном месте, ну нужно использовать префиксы для функций, чтобы избежать конфликтов между модулями, среда разработки всегда точно подсказывает, что можно сделать с объектом. И, разумеется, вы можете воспользоваться *инкапсуляцией*, чтобы скрыть от пользователя поля, в которые он не должен залезать без спроса.

**III.** Следующий шаг возникает, когда *сущности начинают выстраиваться в иерархию*. Например, есть объект (хоть в процедурном, хоть в объектом понимании) "база данных", и вы хотите выполнить запрос. Но база данных не может быть абстрактной, всегда надо использовать конкретную СУБД: MySQL, SQL Server и т.п. Основные методы работы с этими базами данных похожие, и хочется с ними работать по-одинаковому, чтобы можно было при необходимости менять СУБД, не меня код.

Для процедурного программирования естественный ход — это добавить в объект свойство "СУБД" и в функции `do_sql_query` добавить огромный-преогромный `switch` по всем вариантам. Поддерживать такой код становится невероятно сложно, в каждой функции приходится обрабатывать все возможные варианты для всех возможных СУБД.

И вот здесь на помощь приходит **объектно-ориентированное программирование**. Теперь вы можете использовать *наследование*, чтобы построить классы в стройные иерархии, и *полиморфизм*, чтобы организовать вызов "одинаковых" методов в зависимости от положения класса в иерархии.

Так как человеку естественно думать в терминах объектов, а не функций, то объектно-ориентированное программирование хорошо подходит для описания сущностей. Разумеется, те же сущности есть в и процедурном, и в объектом программировании, но именно со всеми возможностями объектно-ориентированного программирования приходит свобода реализовать код красиво и лаконично.

**IV.** В определённый момент даже объектно-ориентированного программирования начинает не хватать: оно предоставляет огромную свободу, и код снова превращается в мешанину из иерархий и виртуальных методов, которые вызываются как попало. Тут на спасение приходят **шаблоны проектирования**, которые описывают, как с помощью объектно-ориентированного программирования можно эффективно организовывать код, как избегать чрезмерной сложности и делать так, чтобы код был понятен остальным.

Другое направление — **обобщённое программирование**, когда с объектами разных типов можно работать одинаковым или похожим способом.

При любой парадигме в сложных программах неизбежно возникают *модули* и другие способы организации кода.

---

Какой язык — объектно-ориентированный или процедурный — значения не имеет. В объектно-ориентированном стиле можно писать на процедурном языке и наоборот.

Кроме того, существует множество парадигм программирования: **функциональное программирование**, **логическое программирование** и другие. Это уже не привычное императивное программирование, но некоторые аспекты того же функционального программирования начинают перебираться в традиционно императивные языки, что позволяет пользоваться многими интересными возможностями.

Answer (score 4):

Полностью поддерживаю [[@lampa](/users/5030/lampa)](/users/5030/lampa) .
В функцию класса можно спокойно засунуть все необходимые проверки. Плюс вспомните, что обычно сайт состоит не из одной страницы, а, к примеру, из 10, и на каждой будет эти 3 строчки + 10 строк проверки входящих параметров, подстановки параметров в строку запроса, проверки результата... И при изменении одной из этих строчек придется менять ее на всех 10ти страницах. А если у вас класс - меняем это только в одном месте и все, на всех страницах будет использоваться уже исправленная или дополненная функция. Как раз класс работы с базой данных это очень хороший пример полезности использования ООП.
а представьте, что вы написали проект, который работает не только с `MySQL`, но и еще может работать с `postgresql` или `sqlite`? Что же на каждой странице делать проверку с какой бд мы работаем в данном случае? фу-фу-фу-фу! Для этого есть class! В нем делаем одну переменную и в зависимости от ее значения используем тот или иной метод работы с базой. Ведь правда же удобно? ;)

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы проектировать и писать сложные вещи. Почитайте книгу [*Мэтт Зандстра* "PHP. Объекты, шаблоны и методики программирования"](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5648968/), если собираетесь использовать ООП подход в полную силу.