# Как, зачем и где используют классы в php  на практике?

Tags: классы, php

Не могу ещё составить и уяснить **практическую** задачу, где без классов не обойтись.
Опыт -  в виде написания самописных сайтиков, и  модулей друпала.

Comment: Классы в других языках, стало быть, вопросов не вызывают? Так вот, в PHP всё точно так же: обойтись без классов можно всегда и в любой задаче.

Comment: @klopp может просто ТС еще других ЯП пока не знает?

Answer (score 2):

[Для чего нужны классы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/170336/php-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B)

Answer (score 1):

Я тоже раньше не понимал.
Для меня классы — это удобство.
Например, в соей CMS у меня реализована стандартная идея — модульный принцип.
У меня есть класс, который обрабатывает запрос и подключает модуль, точнее передает управление инстансу какого-то класса, в котором собраны нужные методы. Разумеется, тоже самое можно достичь обычными функциями (+ неймспейсы). Разумеется, есть всякие плюсы, например, инкапсуляция.
Ввиду того, что в 5.4 появились трейты, наследование я нигде сейчас не использую, т.к. все получается с помощью интерфейсов и трейтов, но возможно придет день и мне понадобится наследование...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class User{
function sum(){
echo 'sum';
}
function sum1(){
echo 'sum1';
}
}
$n = new User();
$n->sum();
$n->sum1();
?>
```

Comment: Это чё было?

Comment: к чему сей пример?

Comment: Мощно :D я бы добавил еще

> function sum3() {
>    $this->sum();
> }