# Практические отличия ООП и процедурного стиля в PHP

Tags: php, ооп

Только начинаю изучать программирование, остановился на php в силу конкретных целей в данной области.
Понимание постепенно приходит, однако все еще не могу понять, чем на практике отличается ООП от процедурного? Все, что было возможно прочесть на эту тему, я прочел. Но зерно понимания никак не даёт ростков, т.к. пока на практике не применишь - не поймешь.

Поэтому интересуют именно практические различия. Допустим, как была бы реализована форма регистрации/авторизации в процедурном стиле и ООП в php? Если такое сравнение вообще корректно.

Говорят, что процедурный стиль — это переменные, функции, циклы и массивы, а ООП - объекты и методы. Значит ли это, что знания, полученные о процедурном стиле совершенно не пригодны в ООП?

Правильно ли мое сравнение, что разные парадигмы в программировании, это как и в разговорном языке - одну и ту же мысль можно просто донести разными словами, например, более лаконично?

Comment: ООП по сути имеет одно предназначение - это удобство программиста - то есть в какой-то момент, вы заходите расширить свою форму авторизации, например, с возможностью входа из github. в случае процедурного стиля, вы это сделаете и создадите дополнительное наследие, в котором другой программист будет разбираться намного дольше. в случае ООП, вы просто расширите поведение (логику) своего класса авторизации и все будет работать как и прежде, понятно для остальных. Надеюсь я описал внятно

Comment: я бы на вашем месте не стал пытаться разобраться с ООП решая задачи "как будет выглядеть форма регистрации в ООП", ибо это комплекс задач затрагивающий множество аспектов. Начните с понимая того, как в ООП будет выглядеть класс Пользователь, и какие методы у него могут быть и т.п. Рассматривайте мелкий составляющие этой задачи. Потом взаимодействие между этими классами.

Comment: Почитайте разные мнения на тему ООП, погуглив `критика ооп`, например --  [это](http://blogerator.org/page/oop_why-objects-have-failed) или [это](https://habrahabr.ru/post/169601/)

Comment: Вспомнил у VladD [хороший пост](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/170480/213987) на эту тему, рекомендую ознакомиться.

Comment: Кстати, а давайте к нему и задубликатим? Даже когда только нажимаешь на закрыть вопрос -- уже сходу система предлагает на выбор два вопроса, один из которых как раз "для чего нужны классы"

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Для чего нужны классы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/170336/%d0%94%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b)

Comment: Объекты проще для понимания человеком чем набор действий (методов). Удобней размышлять над логикой сущностями пользователь -> совершает покупку. Чем Совершает покупку (пользователь)

Answer (score 2):

1. как была бы реализована форма регистрации/авторизации в процедурном стиле и ООП?
   В процедурном стиле форма делалась и обрабатывалась бы с помощью нескольких методов, связанных между собой только параметрами и глобальными переменными. В стиле ООП для формирования и обработки данных, введенных на форме нужно сделать класс, который будет инкапсулировать логику работы формы. Каждый из подходов имеет свои плюсы и свои минусы. Какой из них выбрать определяется во первых - целью, которую нужно достичь, во вторых - квалификацией разработчика.
2. Значит ли это, что знания, полученные о процедурном стиле совершенно не пригодны в ООП?
   С точностью до наоборот. При ООП программировании нужно достаточно хорошо владеть навыками процедурного программирования. И наоборот, при процедурном программировании вполне возможно применение патернов ООП разработки, даже не используя напрямую классы, наследование и полиморфизм. Особенно это касается как раз php. В общем, чем больше опыт разработки в разных парадигмах программирования, тем выше квалификация разработчика и тем больше набор возможных инструментов, которые он может применить в своей работе.
3. Правильно ли мое сравнение, что разные парадигмы в программировании, это как и в разговорном языке - одну и ту же мысль можно просто донести разными словами, например, более лаконично?
   Думаю, что да. Если знаешь только один язык, то объясняться на другом языке довольно сложно. Зная несколько языков - можно выбрать, на каком из них изъясняться в каждой из жизненных ситуаций и в зависимости от того, в какой стране находишься. К тому же, в зависимости от преследуемых целей, можно выбрать более удобный язык, чтобы донести свою мысль до собеседника. Мне нравится это сравнение.

Ну и, наконец,
4. чем на практике отличается ООП от процедурного?
На практике - если пишется небольшая программа с ограниченным набором функций, программа, которую пишет один человек и которую вряд ли придется модифицировать, развивать и поддерживать долгое время - то лучше выбрать процедурный подход. Это более просто, наглядно и быстро.
Если же разрабатываемая программа включает в себя работу со сложной функциональностью, с обработкой нескольких(многих) сущностей, программа, которую будет разрабатывать несколько человек и (или) которой прочится долгая, трудная, многострадальная жизнь, то лучше рассмотреть возможность применить объектно-ориентированный подход. Но это, опять же, очень сильно зависит от постановки задачи и квалификации постановщиков и разработчиков, которые будут участвовать в процессе. Если квалификация низкая, то результат использования ООП может быть как раз намного хуже, чем простое процедурное программирование в связи с тем, что при неграмотном построении структуры классов работа с ними превращается в совершенно немыслимую эквилибристику жонглирования объектами и методами, что приводит, обычно, к полному переписыванию проекта.