# Профессиональное использование ООП

Tags: php, ооп

Вот я не понимаю, почему, когда делают какой-нибудь метод, то у него получается много вложений?

Вот давайте разберём компонент **league/plates**, который есть на сайте **packagist**.
В нём есть метод **render**, если кликнуть на него, то он работает, через метод **make**, который работает, через ещё другой метод render.

Метод **make**, создаёт новый объект, в котором создаётся другой объект и там ещё много всяких вложенностей.
Так вот я к чему, правильно ли я думаю, то, что эти вложенности (очень много небольших методов) создаются, для того, что бы использовать, для других методов, что бы не дублировать код?

Это и есть, правильное использование ооп?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/170480/194569

Comment: К ссылке выше добавлю, что надо иметь ввиду, что не всегда куча вложенностей и многочисленных оберток является образцом правильной архитектуры и применения ООП. Компоненты пишут такие же обычные люди, постоянно их дополняя и совершенствуя. Разумеется, в них также могут быть архитектурные ошибки.

Comment: Профессиональное использование ООП, это когда вы используете максимально правильно весь инструментарий языка. А то, что вы привели в пример, возможно просто было так удобнее автору. Но это не показатель его крутости. В целом, правильное использование ООП - это когда у вас спустя некоторое время возникает желание переписать вашу старую писанину в более правильную модель.

Comment: По сути ООП подразумевает, что кода структурного кода будет больше, файловая структура будет больше и в некоторых местах запутанней. Однако, вот Вы смотрите на любой метод в этой структуре - и практически сразу понимаете, что он делает. Кроме того - это способствует расширяемости, и как правило - лезть в глубокие вложения нет необходимости, а если есть - значит есть ошибка в архитектуре

Answer (score 1):

В заголовке статьи вынесено Профессиональное использование ООП.

Я так понимаю, что вопрос относится к программным системам, разработанным квалифицированными программистами и реализующим достаточно сложную функциональность для того, чтобы применение ООП было оправдано.

Если это так, то можно попробовать ответить на поставленные вопросы.

**почему, когда делают какой-нибудь метод, то у него получается много вложений?**

Потому что в любой большой, грамотно спроектированной ООП системе есть классы с несколькими уровнями наследования. А, следовательно, каждый следующий потомок может вызывать методы своего предка. Поэтому, например, при трех уровнях наследования уже по определению может быть как минимум два уровня вложенности вызовов одного и того же метода. Не считая вызовов интерфейсных методов других классов, которые также можно рассматривать как вложенную функциональность для конкретной функции.

**эти вложенности (очень много небольших методов) создаются, для того, что бы использовать, для других методов, что бы не дублировать код?**

В грамотно спроектированной ООП системе каждый метод должен выполнять только свое предназначение. Следовательно, наличие функций-монстров, которые универсальны и выполняют кучу разных по своему назначению действий, крайне противопоказано в профессиональной системе. Так как системы достаточно сложные (см. мое вводное условие) выполняемых функций много. Следовательно, должно быть много небольших методов, каждый из которых делает то, что нужно. А уже где и как эти методы вызывать решает программист в зависимости от поставленной задачи. Это может быть вызов одного метода другого (или своего) класса в одном методе реализуемого класса. А может быть несколько... Дублировать или не дублировать код зависит от проектирования системы. Иногда ЛУЧШЕ продублировать код, чем делать лишнюю связанность элементов. Например, если есть два параллельных класса, решающих примерно одну задачу, но чуть-чуть по разному. Два подхода - сделать один общий метод в базовом классе (исключение дублирования) или сделать два метода в каждом из этих параллельных классов (дублирование кода). Первый подход нужно выбрать, если выполняемая часть кода полностью идентична и СКОРЕЕ ВСЕГО не будет изменяться в дальнейшем. Второй подход необходимо выбрать в случае, если дублируемая часть кода СКОРЕЕ ВСЕГО будет изменяться или дополняться. Так как в случае, если при первом подходе вдруг понадобится внести изменения в общий для обоих классов код, но необходимый только для одного из классов, то придется усложнять уже реализованный ОБЩИЙ для двух классов код. Что отрицательно скажется на стабильности системы в целом.

**Это и есть, правильное использование ооп?**

Критерии правильности написания кода у каждого программиста разные.

Мало того, даже на каждом проекте они разные.

Я уж не говорю о сообществе программистов в целом.

Поэтому "правильно" или "неправильно" использовано ООП в каждом конкретном случае можно определить только по совокупности некоторых требований, которые предъявляются к системе.

Например, если самым важным требованием к системе считается надежность, то правильное использование ООП будет состоять в грамотном разбиении на сущности и выполняемые этими сущностями функции. Этих функций обычно много. Следовательно, и вложенность будет достаточно большой по сравнению с реализацией такой же системы, например, в структурной парадигме программирования.